# range of x-axis of kdeplot in seaborn is different than in data

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting a `kdeplot` using

```
import seaborn as sns 
colors = ['r','g','b']
i = 0
for v in dt.var.unique():
    p1 = sns.kdeplot(dt.query('var == @v')['val'], shade=True, color=colors[i], legend=None).get_figure()
    i += 1
```

The `dt.val.max()` and the `dt.val.min()` are `350` and `0` respectively.

But the plot looks like this

[image]

I don't understand why the x-axis ranges is not in accordance with the data.

Comment: You can also look at the `cut` option. This will allow you to cut the tails of the kde. This gives visual feedback for where the data ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kde puts a gaussian bell shape over each of the data points and sums all those shapes. The width of the shape depends on the number of points (or can be given as a parameter) and the variance of the data. When there are fewer sample points, the bell shapes get wider. Probably your red curve has few sample points, and most of them are close to 0 or 350.

Currently, seaborn uses [`scipy.statsmodels.nonparametric.kde.KDEUnivariate`](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.kde.KDEUnivariate.html) with the [formula](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/_modules/statsmodels/nonparametric/kde.html#KDEUnivariate) `1.059 * std(samples) * len(samples) ** (-1/5)` for the width of the gaussian normal.

In general, a kdeplot is meant for continuous distributions with enough sample points and supposing the probability density function is rather smooth.

The following code tries to illustrate how the kde curve is calculated as the sum of the individual gaussian curves, starting from a simplified distribution of sample points. These sample points give rise to a kde curve resembling the red curve of the example.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats as stats

values = [0, 200, 300, 350]
repeats = [100, 25, 35, 40]
samples = np.repeat(values, repeats)
sns.kdeplot(samples, shade=False, color='crimson', label='kdeplot')

sigma = 1.059 * samples.std() * len(samples) ** (-1/5.)
x = np.linspace(-150, 500, 500)
for val, rep in zip(values, repeats):
    f = stats.norm.pdf(x, val, sigma)
    plt.plot(x, f * rep / len(samples), ls=':', label=f'value: {val} freq: {rep}')
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]