# Plotting weighted histograms with weighted KDE (kernel density estimate)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram, kernel-density

I want to plot two distributions of data as weighted histograms with weighted kernel density estimate (KDE) plots, side by side.

The data (`length` of DNA fragments, split by categorical variable `regions`) are integers in `(0, 1e8)` interval. I can plot the default, unweighted, histograms and KDE without a problem, using the python code below. The code plots histograms for the tiny example of the input data in `testdata` variable. See the unweighted (default) histograms below.

I want to produce a different plot, where the data in the histograms are **weighted** by `length` (= the X axis numeric variable). I used `weights` option ([seaborn.histplot — seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html)):

> `weights` : vector or key in `data`
> If provided, weight the contribution of the corresponding data points towards the count in each bin by these factors.

The histograms changed as expected (see weighted histograms plots below). *But the KDE (kernel density estimate) lines did not change.*

**Question: How can I change the kernel density estimate (KDE) to reflect the fact that I am using weighted histograms?**

---

Unweighted (default) histograms:

[image: Unweighted (default) histograms]

---

Weighted histograms:

[image: Weighted histograms]

---

Code with the minimal reproducible example:

```
import io
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

def plot_restriction_digest(df, out_file_base, weights):
     
    # Prevent the python icon from showing in the dock when the script is
    # running:
    matplotlib.use('Agg')
    
    sns.set_theme(style='ticks')
    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 5))
    sns.despine(f)

    hist = sns.histplot(data=df,
                        x='length',
                        hue='regions',

                        weights=weights,
                        
                        # Normalize such that the total area of the histogram
                        # equals 1:
                        stat='density',
                        
                        # stat='count',
                        
                        # Make all histograms visible, otherwise 'captured'
                        # regions histogram is much smaller than 'all' regions
                        # one:
                        common_norm=False,
                        
                        # Default plots too many very thin bins, which are poorly
                        # visible in pdf format (OK in png). Note that 10 bins is
                        # too crude, and 1000 bins makes too many thin bins:
                        bins=100,
                        
                        # X axis log scale:
                        log_scale=True,
                        
                        # Compute a kernel density estimate to smooth the
                        # distribution and show on the plot as lines:
                        kde=True,
                        )
    sns.move_legend(hist, 'upper left')
    plt.savefig(f'{out_file_base}.pdf')
    return

testdata="""
1   all
1   all
2   all
2   all
2   all
3   all
4   captured
4   captured
5   captured
5   captured
5   captured
8   captured
"""

# Default histograms:
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(testdata), sep='\s+', header=None, names='length regions'.split())
plot_restriction_digest(df, 'test_tiny', None)

# Weighted histograms:
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(testdata), sep='\s+', header=None, names='length regions'.split())
plot_restriction_digest(df, 'test_tiny_weighted', 'length')

print('Done.')
```

**Notes:**

1. The two distributions of data are DNA fragment lengths for two types of genomic regions: "all" and "captured", but this is irrelevant to this specific question.
2. The minimal reproducible example illustrates the question. The real data frame has tens of millions of rows, so the histograms and KDE plots are much more smooth an meaningful. The actual data need the X axis to be log-transformed to better tell the two broad distributions apart.
3. I am using these packages and versions:

```
Python 3.11.6

matplotlib-base           3.8.2           py311hfdba5f6_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.26.3          py311h7125741_0    conda-forge
pandas                    2.2.0           py311hfbe21a1_0    conda-forge
seaborn                   0.13.1               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
seaborn-base              0.13.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: Does reducing the bandwidth help? Something like `sns.histplot(..., kde_kws={'bw_adjust':0.3})` would reduce the bandwidth to 30%. Some quick tests suggest me the kde correctly takes both the weights and the log scale into account. Could you add an image of how the weighted plot with your real data looks like?  If the code is too slow with your full dataframe, you can try `sns.histplot(df.sample(10000), ....)` to work with a random subset for testing.

Comment: @JohanC (a) Yes, reducing the bandwidth as you suggested fixed the issue for the tiny MRE dataframe. (b) I further tested with 2 simulated different uniform distributions with N=1e7 data points, omitting the log scale to make manual comparisons easier, and without `kde_kws={'bw_adjust':0.3}`. I thus confirmed that kde appears correct by eye in these cases. This is a realistic size dataframe. This confirms your other suggestion. Thus, my question was caused by a test artifact, and there is in fact no issue with kde.

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for your suggestions and tests. If you want to convert your comments into an answer, no matter how brief, I will be happy to accept it! I think it will be valuable to others, for example (a) the confirmation that kde takes into account the weights (not obvious from the docs), (b) using bandwidth to adjust the kde (not obvious from `sns.histplot` help, and obvious only in retrospect, and (c) using realistic size in addition to tiny tests for things like histograms and kde. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Histograms and kde plots with a very small sample size often aren't a good indicator for how things behave with more suitable sample sizes. In this case, the default bandwidth seems too wide for this particular dataset. The bandwidth can be scaled via the `bw_adjust` parameter of the `kdeplot`. When creating a `histplot`, parameters ("keywords") for the `kde` can be provided via the `kde_kws` dictionary.

In my test, to both test weights and a log scale, I used a few `x` values, and gave each a weight of 1, except for two of them, giving them a really high weight.

A log scale can be mimicked by taking the log of the x values. The axis will show the log values, which will be less intuitive than the original values.
For small data sets and integer weights, `np.repeat` can create a dataset with every value repeated. This doesn't work for very large datasets due to memory constraints.

To quickly test settings and behavior for the real dataset, waiting time can be reduced by taking a random sample (e.g. `df.sample(10000)`).

The test code below indicates that both the weights and the log scale seem to work as expected.  One difference is that the default bandwidth is different in both cases; a different `bw_scale` is used to compensate.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
                   'w': [1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1]})
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(9, 6))

sns.histplot(df, x='x', bins=10, weights='w', kde=True, log_scale=True, stat='density',
             kde_kws={'bw_adjust': 0.3}, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xticks(df['x'].to_numpy(), df['x'].to_numpy())
ax1.set_title('sns.histplot with log scale, weights and kde')

sns.histplot(x=np.log(np.repeat(df['x'], df['w'])), bins=10, kde=True, stat='density',
             kde_kws={'bw_adjust': 0.55}, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('mimicing scale and weights')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot with weights, kde and log scale]

Comment: Your comments and answer were very helpful! The solution and explanations also provided a few insights for me. For example, kde/bandwidth is a fundamental piece of knowledge, and is discussed in many sources (even though not in the `histplot` manual). So "RTFM" means "learn the fundamentals about the system", beyond the manual. Another insight is not to limit myself to tiny input datasets in testing. Real-life size datasets as test inputs can be useful - and not just for tings like benchmarking.

Comment: Glad to help. The [Wikipedia article about KDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) has an interesting discussion, a.o. about the bandwidth.  You might also be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71541076/12046409) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62722401/12046409) about creating a KDE more manually, as a sum of gaussians with a given sigma. Seaborn's manual limits itself to the visualization aspects, as a deep-dive into statistics could be a never-ending story. When in doubt, StackOverflow often can help.